# Get XML Node Value from InfoPath XML

Tags: xml, sharepoint, infopath

I have an XML with this NODE, I need to get that value using c#

```
<my:TipoDeGasto>Gastos Regulares</my:TipoDeGasto>
```

I have the following code

```
var myDoc = new XmlDocument();
myDoc.Load(urlFile);

XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(myDoc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("my", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2014-07-12T15:29:09");

var tipoDeGasto = myDoc.SelectSingleNode("/my:TipoDeGasto", ns);
```

But I get tipoDeGasto == null

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to get&set infopath form field value, you could try it.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp:12001/"))
            {
                var web = clientContext.Web;
                var myList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Mydoc2");
                var item = myList.GetItemById(6);

                XmlDocument xmlItem = new XmlDocument();

                //Open XML file and load it into XML document
                var _File = item.File;
                ClientResult<Stream> clientResult = _File.OpenBinaryStream();
                clientContext.Load(_File, F => F.ServerRelativeUrl);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                using (var memory = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 64];
                    int nread = 0;
                    while ((nread = clientResult.Value.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        memory.Write(buffer, 0, nread);
                    }
                    memory.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    xmlItem.Load(memory);
                }
                XPathNavigator navItem = xmlItem.CreateNavigator();

                //Redefine NameSpaceManager (Generate the NameSpace manager for this item)
                navItem.MoveToFollowing(XPathNodeType.Element);
                XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());

                foreach (var ns in navItem.GetNamespacesInScope(XmlNamespaceScope.All))
                {
                    if (ns.Key == String.Empty)
                    {
                        nsManager.AddNamespace("def", ns.Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nsManager.AddNamespace(ns.Key, ns.Value);
                    }
                }

                //Change your value here….
                var node=navItem.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:field2", nsManager);
                node.SetValue("NewValue");
                //Save the modified xml into the item
                byte[] xmlData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlItem.OuterXml);
                Stream NewStream = new MemoryStream(xmlData);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, _File.ServerRelativeUrl, NewStream, true); 
                //item.File.SaveBinary(xmlData);
                item.Update();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```